# Problem in downloading videos using youtube-dl from unsupported sites

Tags: youtube-dl

How can I download videos from "https://unacademy.com/" using youtube-dl?

I had tried, but not succeed and searched, but I did not find a solution. In the Android app for this academy, videos are freely downloadable. Is it possible?

Comment: Short answer: You can't.

Comment: video downloadhelper will probably do this.

Comment: Do you have an example link to a specific video?

Comment: https://unacademy.com/lesson/overview-of-the-course-in-hindi/9D2BXQ6A/?source=Course

Answer (score 11):

You can't, there's no support for that site yet.

The best thing you could do, probably ask youtube-dl developer to add support to your desired site, login to GitHub and propose new issue https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/new/choose, label them `site-support-request`

There's plenty people already done the same as you are → https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/labels/site-support-request

[image]

Comment: The best thing to do is to implement support for this site and send PR to developers, for everyone's benefit. One of the top reasons to use open source license is to give everyone ability to modify and improve the program. If you can't implement support for new site, asking community to do it is probably the second-best thing to do.

Comment: @MirosławZalewski to me such suggestions always felt disingeniuous - it is quite obvious that only a fraction of a software users are a competent developers on the language and system that the target software use. In all likelyhood if the asker could implement it themselves they would not have to ask the question.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh For me, it's important to educate users about this possibility. You are right that they probably can't implement change themselves now, but maybe one day they will be. So it's worth to remind that this option is on the table.

Comment: @MirosławZalewski, sorry this sounds even more out of touch to me. Will my mom (who'd like to save some videos locally) implement it in future? Will my brother who is a brilliant lawyer do this? Or will my cousin twice removed who is a kitchen hand but who is very happy with her job? They are interested in using software, but you cannot really expect that one day they will contribute in its development. This is just unrealistic. So for majority of people you are sending "your message" to it has very little value to none. Those who are interested will most likely get there on their own

Comment: @MirosławZalewski but I might imagine, that for the same majority pointing at an option that is and will always be out of reach is just frustrating.

Answer (score 5):

By design, you cannot download videos using youtube-dl from unsupported sites ;) Indeed, downloading video automatically from a website requires the application to know the specific structure of the site, in order to extract information about the video stream and redirect the stream to a file on your disk. Support to extract video from your site would need to be added to the application for it to work.

Comment: You'd think "By design, you cannot download videos using youtube-dl from unsupported sites" would be pretty obvious.

Comment: @RonJohn, note the title of the question and the smily in my reply.

Comment: Well, wouldn't a mode allowing you to say "assume this site is same structure as site Y, and give it a try" work in most cases

Comment: Would it not be possible to construct a more generic downloader that simply checks for any video tag and parses through iframes? No, it wouldn't work on every site, but it would work for many. (Even more if you could throw in an adblock list of domains to avoid downloading videos from.)

Comment: @rackandboneman on what basis -- besides hope -- are you saying that it would "work in most cases"?

Comment: Because few video platforms are written from scratch and really that different from everyone else.

Comment: Also, there are only so many ways to embed stuff in HTML5, and also only certain useful ways to embed flash videos (and get by eg crossdomain restrictions).